# Query on install selenium webdriver on android for python programming

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have searched fhe forum and this may be one of the ways to install selenium webdriver on android for python programming. However, I am quite confused on how to achieve it as like the link below.Any video or tutorial guide for that?

https://github.com/truebit/AndroidWebDriver4Python

Or is there a better way to install selenium webdriver on android *without pc*.

Answer (score 0):

You may use maven or gradle to import the selenium as dependencies. Please refer http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_installing_java_driver_Sel20_via_maven.jsp#importing-maven-into-intellij-reference.

Dependecy for gradle will be `compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.141.59'`

Dependency for maven will be

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: HI, @Sonali. Thanks for your help . Does it mean we need to connect to pc through usb every time we want to use selenium webdriver on android? Or is this an one-time process to download webdriver using pc to android? Because for time being my laptop is damaged, and thus wish to try to practice code using android instead.

Comment: No, it will download the selenium jar via build tool. Unless you want to rebuild it will be there